# Modified Device Tree for BeagleBone Black Running Yocto Poky to Enable UART4 causing Kernel Halt

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, beagleboneblack, device-tree

I have recently tried to take some steps into learning how to use Yocto and leverage some of the functionality provided. I have a BeagleBone Black and wanted to use this as my device to build a custom kernel using Yocto. I have been following the following tutorial series to understand the basics of yocto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vsu67uMcko&list=PLEBQazB0HUyTpoJoZecRK6PpDG31Y7RPB.

My current objective is to patch the existing device tree used by the Poky reference distribution to enable UART4, the UART port that is accessible through the BeagleBone Black through GPIO header.

I have taken a look at the am335x-boneblack.dts file and the included `dtsi` files and understand which files need to be modified to enable the UART4 port. In specific, I see that the `am335x-bone-common.dtsi` and `am33xx-l4.dtsi` files have pertinent snippets of information related to UART.

The patch file that I add to a new layer and apply is shown below:

```
diff --git a/orig/am335x-bone-common.dtsi b/altered/am335x-bone-common.dtsi
index 0ccdc7c..8a2541c 100644
--- a/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-bone-common.dtsi
+++ b/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-bone-common.dtsi
@@ -95,6 +95,14 @@
                        AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_UART0_TXD, PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN, MUX_MODE0)
                >;
        };
+       
+       uart4_pins: pinmux_uart4_pins {
+               pinctrl-single,pins = <
+                       AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_GPMC_WAIT0, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP, MUX_MODE6)
+                       AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_GPMC_WPN, PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN, MUX_MODE6)
+               >;
+       };
+

        clkout2_pin: pinmux_clkout2_pin {
                pinctrl-single,pins = <
@@ -191,6 +199,13 @@
        status = "okay";
 };

+&uart4 {
+       pinctrl-names = "default";
+       pinctrl-0 = <&uart4_pins>;
+
+       status = "okay";
+};
+
 &usb0 {
        dr_mode = "peripheral";
        interrupts-extended = <&intc 18 &tps 0>;
diff --git a/orig/am33xx-l4.dtsi b/altered/am33xx-l4.dtsi
index c9629cb..637a1a7 100644
--- a/arch/arm/boot/dts/am33xx-l4.dtsi
+++ b/arch/arm/boot/dts/am33xx-l4.dtsi
@@ -1802,7 +1802,7 @@
                                clock-frequency = <48000000>;
                                reg = <0x0 0x1000>;
                                interrupts = <45>;
-                               status = "disabled";
+                               status = "okay";
                        };
                };
```

When I build my kernel, the resulting `.dtb` file reflects the changes, however when I try to boot off of the SD card, the beaglebone halts at

```
Starting kernel ...
```

If anyone can offer some help, I'd be greatful!

Regards

Comment: After debugging further, I noticed that if I simply just make the change within `am33xx-l4.dtsi` file from the status of  `disabled` to `okay`, it is causing the kernel to crash at some point. This may narrow down the scope of the issue.

Comment: In light of the recent comment I made, I am going to make the assumption that since I removed all of the pin muxing changes from the patch file and still resulted in a kernel halt, maybe I was not pin muxing properly to begin with. The other option is that I am not doing this correctly whatsoever. I will go ahead and use another pin when pin muxing as UART4 rx and tx pins can be connected using other pins. I will try to test that out.

Comment: I don't know why it's halting, but you shouldn't need to set `status = "okay";` in `uart4: serial@0 {` in `am33xx-l4.dtsi` because it will be overridden by the `status = "okay";` in `&uart4 {` in `am335x-bone-common.dtsi`.

Comment: Yes! I just realized that today, I removed that unnecessary change, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: As a general rule, the **.dtsi** files that you're patching should not be modified.  Those files are low-level files that describe a generic and basic SoC.  They are included by many other **.dts** (and **.dtsi**) files for other boards.  Instead, your customizations should be at the top-level **.dts** file for only your board.  Or create a new **.dtsi** file of all of your changes, and then **#include** that file at the *end* of the **.dts**.

Comment: "*beaglebone halts at ... Starting kernel ...*" -- That message is from U-Boot.  To get more info, you need to (a) enable verbose kernel decompression, and (b) enable earlyconsole (or earlyprintk).  If the boot still hangs w/o any messages, then your boot loading is suspect (i.e. you don't have valid images or one is overwriting another when loading).  IOW until you have more info, you have a typical boot hang problem that may not related to any DT changes.

Comment: I will go ahead and try to do these changes, thankyou!

Comment: So, for some reason, when I built an earlier kernel version of yocto poky (version dunfell), it actually worked and I can see the new device. I will try to debug further.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, the hardware serial ports are getting remapped.  I suspect because you're trying to configure more hardware ports than you've allowed for in the kernel configuration.

Look at the kernel configuration, and specifically change:

```
CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_NR_UARTS=4
CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_RUNTIME_UARTS=4
```

to

```
CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_NR_UARTS=5
CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_RUNTIME_UARTS=5
```

I had the same issue, and worse, enabling still more hardware UARTS in the dts eventually got the system to the point that the debug port wasn't showing up at all in the list of 4.  Changed this setting, and the list of 4 became a list of 5, and everything came back into line, so that the debug port is back at ttyS0, and everything else follows the BBB pin names.

Also, from the help text for CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_OMAP:
"This driver uses ttyS instead of ttyO"

Answer (score 0):

So, it would seem that the kernel doesn't really hang when enabling UART4.
For some reason, UART4 gets mapped to ttyS0 - which breaks the console output.

Setup:
Beaglebone Black - Yocto Kirkstone - Machine: beaglebone-yocto.

This is the relevant part from am335x-bone-common.dtsi:

```
uart0_pins: pinmux_uart0_pins {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_UART0_RXD, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP, MUX_MODE0)   /* Debug Header - UART0_RX */
        AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_UART0_TXD, PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN, MUX_MODE0)    /* Debug Header - UART0_TX */
    >;
};

uart1_pins: pinmux_uart1_pins {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_UART1_RXD, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP, MUX_MODE0)   /* P9-26 UART1_RX */
        AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_UART1_TXD, PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN, MUX_MODE0)    /* P9-24 UART1_TX */
    >;
};

uart2_pins: pinmux_uart2_pins {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_SPI0_SCLK, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP, MUX_MODE1)   /* P9-22 UART2_RX */
        AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_SPI0_D0, PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN, MUX_MODE1)      /* P9-21 UART2_TX */
    >;
};

uart4_pins: pinmux_uart4_pins {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_GPMC_WAIT0, PIN_INPUT, MUX_MODE6)     /* P9-11 UART4_RX */    
        AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_GPMC_WPN, PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN, MUX_MODE6) /* P9-13 UART4_TX */    
    >;
};
```

Once the board boots - I can SSH into it from Ethernet. Here's the output from pinctrl and serial:

```
root@beaglebone-yocto:~# cat /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/pinctrl-maps 
Pinctrl maps:
device 44e10800.pinmux
state default
type MUX_GROUP (2)
controlling device 44e10800.pinmux
group pinmux_clkout2_pin
function pinmux_clkout2_pin

device 48022000.serial
state default
type MUX_GROUP (2)
controlling device 44e10800.pinmux
group pinmux_uart1_pins
function pinmux_uart1_pins

device 48024000.serial
state default
type MUX_GROUP (2)
controlling device 44e10800.pinmux
group pinmux_uart2_pins
function pinmux_uart2_pins

device 4819c000.i2c
state default
type MUX_GROUP (2)
controlling device 44e10800.pinmux
group pinmux_i2c2_pins
function pinmux_i2c2_pins

device 481a8000.serial
state default
type MUX_GROUP (2)
controlling device 44e10800.pinmux
group pinmux_uart4_pins
function pinmux_uart4_pins

device 4a100000.switch
state default
type MUX_GROUP (2)
controlling device 44e10800.pinmux
group cpsw_default
function cpsw_default

device 4a100000.switch
state sleep
type MUX_GROUP (2)
controlling device 44e10800.pinmux
group cpsw_sleep
function cpsw_sleep

device 4a101000.mdio
state default
type MUX_GROUP (2)
controlling device 44e10800.pinmux
group davinci_mdio_default
function davinci_mdio_default

device 4a101000.mdio
state sleep
type MUX_GROUP (2)
controlling device 44e10800.pinmux
group davinci_mdio_sleep
function davinci_mdio_sleep

device 44e09000.serial
state default
type MUX_GROUP (2)
controlling device 44e10800.pinmux
group pinmux_uart0_pins
function pinmux_uart0_pins

device 44e0b000.i2c
state default
type MUX_GROUP (2)
controlling device 44e10800.pinmux
group pinmux_i2c0_pins
function pinmux_i2c0_pins

device 48060000.mmc
state default
type MUX_GROUP (2)
controlling device 44e10800.pinmux
group pinmux_mmc1_pins
function pinmux_mmc1_pins

device 481d8000.mmc
state default
type MUX_GROUP (2)
controlling device 44e10800.pinmux
group pinmux_emmc_pins
function pinmux_emmc_pins

root@beaglebone-yocto:~# cat /proc/tty/driver/serial
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:8250 mmio:0x481A8000 irq:35 tx:871 rx:0 RTS|CTS|DTR|DSR
1: uart:8250 mmio:0x48022000 irq:24 tx:0 rx:0 CTS|DSR|CD|RI
2: uart:8250 mmio:0x48024000 irq:25 tx:0 rx:0 CTS|DSR
3: uart:8250 mmio:0x44E09000 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0 CTS|D
```

As you can see, UART4 gets mapped to /dev/ttyS0 and UART0 gets mapped to /dev/ttyS3 after bootup.

I'm not sure why UART4 gets mapped to ttyS0 and not ttyS4.

I can't even see /dev/ttyS4 despite it being an alias in the am33xx.dtsi

```
root@beaglebone-yocto:~# ls -la /dev/ttyS*
crw--w---- 1 root tty     4, 64 Mar  9 12:45 /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 65 Jan  1  2000 /dev/ttyS1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 66 Jan  1  2000 /dev/ttyS2
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 67 Jan  1  2000 /dev/ttyS3
```